# Why no alsa device for usb soundcard for vlc to use?

Tags: usb, sound, alsa, vlc, tv-tuner

I have 14.04 nicely installed and running on an old mac mini.  I want to wireless stream video around my home with a Kworld DVD Maker 2 USB video capture card and VLC, like I did nicely for years under 10.10. Since upgrading, video still works perfectly, but sound is tricky. I can record sound from the USB device with Audacity (default settings), but can't play sound from it with VLC or mplayer, seemingly because no `hw:1,0` alsa device is being created for VLC to use, like it used to be under 10.10.

Surely this is fixable as sound is entering the box - I seem to be so close. Any help much appreciated as it will save good money on expensive alternatives such as a Slingbox!

Here's what I know:

**Extracted USB device info**

```
$ sudo lsusb -v | less

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1b80:e304 Afatech 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1b80 Afatech
  idProduct          0xe304 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                1 USB 2861 Device
```

**Drivers seem to be successfully loaded**

```
$ dmesg

[ 8476.901213] em2860 #0: Identified as Pinnacle Dazzle DVC 90/100/101/107 / Kaiser Baas Video to DVD maker / Kworld DVD Maker 2 / Plextor ConvertX PX-AV100U (card=9)
[ 8476.901216] em2860 #0: analog set to isoc mode.
[ 8476.901375] em28xx audio device (1b80:e304): interface 1, class 1
[ 8476.901410] em2860 #0: Registering V4L2 extension
[ 8477.433199] saa7115 2-0025: saa7113 found @ 0x4a (em2860 #0)
[ 8478.872985] em2860 #0: V4L2 video device registered as video0
[ 8478.872989] em2860 #0: V4L2 VBI device registered as vbi0
[ 8478.872992] em2860 #0: V4L2 extension successfully initialized
```

**Sound device seems to be recognized**

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards 

0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0x53480000 irq 23

1 [Device         ]: USB-Audio - USB 2861 Device
                      USB 2861 Device at usb-0000:00:04.1-3, high speed
```

**But no USB device shows under `aplay -l`**

(I am a member of the audio group, so I don't think it is  a permissions issue)

```
$  aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 0: ALC889A Analog [ALC889A Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 1: ALC889A Digital [ALC889A Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**Ubuntu sound app settings**

These show a "Line In *USB 2861 Device*" and the Input Level indicator flickers nicely to show sound is being received.

**No luck with trying to force alsa to create a `hw1,0` alias**

I followed [these advices](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UsbAudioDevices)  and adjusted `alsa-base.conf` with appropriate edits, but it seems to make no difference: still no USB device under `aplay -l`.

Comment: Thanks David for the edits - I'm new to this, so much appreciated. Since posting the question I have discovered that a soundcard for recording  is created (viewable under arecord -l and alsamixer), but no playback device is being created. So it seems likely that the latest em28xx driver is not doing what the old one used to do. More importantly, I discovered a nice site likely to help me solve this: http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Em28xx_devices. So as not to waste anyone else's time here, I will try their mailing list and post any conclusions here. Thanks to all who tried to help!